# How does one disable the right-click context menu in Flash?

Tags: flash, browser-based-games

I happened to play around with [habbo.com](http://www.habbo.com/) social game portal.

It clearly uses Adobe Flash as platform (if you look into the source code of the HTML page). But when you do right mouse click you don't get the Flash right-click menu popping up!

Does anybody have an idea how this is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's more a question for StackOverflow, but anyway ...

The idea is to disable the right-click menu in the *JavaScript* of the page, then pass that event to the underlying Flash application via the [ExternalInterface class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) (`ExternalInterface.addCallback("rightClick", rightClickHandlerMethod);` or similar).

An example application with source code can be found on the Another-D-Mention blog in the "[Right click and custom context menu in Flash/Flex](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/right-click-and-custom-context-menu-in-flash-flex/)" article.